# Web Service Method skipped?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm using an ASP.NET application with a web service, and for some reason one of the web service methods gets skipped.  I'm sure it's a fairly simple problem, but it's had me stumped for over a day.  Am I putting the method call in the wrong method, I would assume OnPreRender would handle everything before the page finshes loading.  I am fairly confident that the problem is in this area, if I set the form object's ImageLoc to a URL when it is instantiated it loads in the ASP.NET page just fine.

I don't think I left out any relevant code, but if you need to see anything else let me know.  The form object is just a few properties with get/set so I left it out.  Also please note that String parameters will be changed to something else, I am just trying to get the ground work set up.

.aspx.cs :

```
     localhost.MobileFormServices wsMobile = new localhost.MobileFormServices();

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        //Call the web service to pass image URL 
        wsMobile.NewForm("parameters");
        FormImage.ImageUrl = wsMobile.FormProperties().ImageLoc;
    }
```

web service methods:

```
   //new form object instance
    private FormLibrary.Form form = new FormLibrary.Form();

    //adds the image location to the form object
    [WebMethod]
    public void NewForm(String parameters)
    {
        form.ImageLoc = "http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg"; //breakpoint here, never hit
    }

   [WebMethod]
    public FormLibrary.Form FormProperties() 
    {
        return this.form;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure web service isn't called? The call

```
FormImage.ImageUrl = wsMobile.FormProperties().ImageLoc;
```

although uses same object instance on your page calls completely different instance on Web Service side than when method

```
 wsMobile.NewForm("parameters");
```

was called. Because of that

```
private FormLibrary.Form form = new FormLibrary.Form();
```

is called on every web service call.

On every web service call new instance of web service handling the call is created.
So in your example.

1. wsMobile.NewForm("parameters") - new FormLibrary.Form is created when instance handling this call is created.
2. in this call you set form.ImageLoc - but this form is local to that instance
3. FormImage.ImageUrl = wsMobile.FormProperties().ImageLoc; - again new FormLibrary.Form is created for instance handling this call
4. you return ImageLoc of new created FormLibrary.Form. Not what you previously set.

Comment: That makes sense to me, but how would you recommend fixing this?

Comment: I gave it some thought, would passing a form object to the asp.net application, using/modifying it, and then passing it back through the web service resolve it?  I am going to try that now.

Comment: You can store FormLibrary.Form as static, but that would end in all pages sharing same Form which is probably bad but depends on each project. Other way is to store it in Session or in some external store like database. Or if you are really using two calls in your app maybe you should make it one? In this example second call doesn't make sense. First call should return what you need.  If you find this answer useful please upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using OnPreRenderComplete event instead of OnPreRender.

Comment: Tried that, had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the debugger gets confused.  Try this (and do a rebuild all):

```
[WebMethod]
public void NewForm(String parameters)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    form.ImageLoc = "http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg"; //breakpoint here, never hit
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't make it to here, so that means it deifinitely is not being called?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Are you making sure IIS is shut down and restarted (or what ever the server is) between tests?  Try deleting and re-adding the proxy.

Comment: No error message, basically I am going to use the web service to access some images generated by another program(not yet made, that's why I'm using a random image).  I am trying to pass that image to my asp.net application to display it. I have tried restarting the server I'm using.  Do you mean the proxy class? I've tried that as well.  I did some reading and I thought this was perhaps an xml parsing problem that occurs when you pass objects from webservices, but the solution for that didn't change anything for me(deleting the form class in the proxy and adding using FormLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your OnPreRender() code to OnInit().

Comment: No change, still skips the breakpoint and does not perform as expected.

Comment: Why would that change anything?